# `Get-SPOUser` is denied but `Set-SPOUser` works

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, spo

Using the credentials for a SharePoint Administrator user (`User-X`), I can successfully run the `Set-SPOUser` commands but **not** the `Get-SPOUser` command.

```
PS > Connect-SPOService -Url "https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com"    # Successful
PS > Get-SPOUser -Site "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Site-A"   # Unsuccessful
PS > Set-SPOUser -Site "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Site-A"   # Successful
```

Here is the error returned from the `Get-SPOUser` command:

`Get-SPOUser : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))`

`User-X` is **not** a Site Collection Administrator for `Site-A` but they are a SharePoint Admin for the tenant that `Site-A` is a part of.

I noticed that when I manually add `User-X` to `Site-A` as a Site Collection Admin through the SharePoint Admin Center (or through `Set-SPOUser ... -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $true`), then I am able to successfully run `Get-SPOUser`.

**Why am I unable to run `Get-SPOUser` with a SharePoint Administrator?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No M365 Admin Role (SharePoint Admin, Global Admin) automatically gives rights to *sites*, *site content*, and so on. You must have the appropriate rights at the site/group level.

On SharePoint Server we solved this via Web Application policies, granting Farm Admins 'Full Control' over the entire Web Application, thus there was no requirement to explicitly add an admin to a site to take action against it. This does not exist in SPO, thus you must add your admin to the site to take action against the site.

In other words, this is by design/expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the response Trevor.
Why can I see the Site Collection Admins and group membership (Owners, Visitors, Members) from the SharePoint Admin Center though?

Comment: Because Microsoft exposes the interface via API calls.